# What winbox alternatives are available for 12.04

Tags: software-recommendation

Winbox is an application which is use to remotely access a mikrotik board. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I need an urgent alternative to that software. Any suggestion would be appreciated, but ideally would be referred.

Comment: Winbox is reported to [run on Wine](http://www.goletdoit.com/winbox-on-linux/). Have you tried that?

Comment: yup working thank you very much @LuísdeSousa it helps alot

Answer (score 2):

You can run `Winbox` on Ubuntu using `wine`. Install `wine` by:

```
apt-get install wine
```

Run it using `wine`:

```
wine winbox.exe
```